# How do I get the data to return with multiple elements?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How do I get the data to return in multiple title elements rather than one title element?

Returns this

```
<title>
    Title 1
    Title 2
    Title 3
</title>
```

Want to return this

```
<title>Title 1</title>
<title>Title 2</title>
<title>Title 3</title>
```

Code

```
(: This gets coordinates from $latLon :)
  let $result := for $coordinates in $latLon/location
                let $lat := $coordinates/lat/text()
                let $lon := $coordinates/lon/text()
(: This uses the coordinates to retrieve a title :)
                let $data := titleDoc:getTitle($lat, $lon)
                let $title := $data//div[@class="title"]/text()
                return
                  <title>{$title}</title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to answer without seeing the contents of $data.
But something like this should work:

```
for $title in $data//div[@class="title"]
return <title>{data($title)}</title>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @chrisis says, it's hard to tell without looking at your code, but I think you want a `for` instead of a `let` here:

```
  let $title := $data//div[@class="title"]/text()
  return <title>{$title}</title>
```

The `let` makes one sequence with all the text nodes, and places them in the `<title>` element.  That's not what you want, you want to iterate over them, creating one title element for each one:

```
  for $title in $data//div[@class="title"]/text()
  return <title>{$title}</title>
```